# Using JQuery, how do I check that a string is a letter character followed by eight digits?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm a beginner writing JQuery to add to a customization form website. Most of the options are drag and drop, but I have to write custom jquery in some cases.

For this, I've been able to figure out to validate a nine-character string so that an error message is presented if the string is NOT 9 characters long, and if it starts with anything other than "B", "E", or "N."

However, it also needs to check and make sure that all other characters after the first is a digit. For instance, an acceptable user input would be e00012345.

What is the simplest way to do this?

```js
// this validation will check to make sure that an accepted value is entered into a field.
// currently, the validation is not perfect. Ideally, the value would start with a specific character (n, b or e) and 8 digits. Right now it just must start with n, b or e and be 9 characters long. 

$(function() {

  // for the Missouri Business Number -- on blur, if the value is 9 characters long and starts with b, e, or n (uppoer or lower case), then the input is valid. Otherwise, error messages appear.

$("input#id_wrT4duNEOW").blur(function() {
    if (
        (($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().startsWith("b")) &&
        ($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().length == 9)) ||
        (($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().startsWith("e")) && 
        ($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().length == 9)) || 
        (($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().startsWith("n")) && 
        ($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().length == 9)) || 
        (($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().startsWith("B")) && 
        ($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().length == 9)) || 
        (($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().startsWith("E")) && 
        ($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().length == 9)) || 
        (($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().startsWith("N")) && 
        ($("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val().length == 9))
    ) 
    {
      // good things happen
    } 
else {
     // error message
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

***EDIT***

Okay, I tried adding in the regex line, but I'm not getting the result. What am I missing?

```
$(function() {

$("input#id_wrT4duNEOW").blur(function() {
    const regex = /^[bBeEnN]{1}[0-9]{8}$/
    var mobiz = $("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val();
    if (console.log(regex.test(mobiz)))
    {
      // good things happen
    } 
else {
     // error message
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This isn't so much a jquery question, but a regex question

Comment: I hate to be dense (only started coding a month ago as a last-resort solution), but when I was trying to add in validation using regex expressions I found on stackoverflow, I couldn't always get them to work. What is regex -- as in, how is it "not" jquery?

Comment: Regex (Regular Expressions) is a form of pattern matching against strings.  It is logic existing in vanilla javascript.  jQuery is a library built upon javascript, with the intent of normalizing common methods and logic associated with accessing and manipulating the dom across different browsers and within different browser versions.

Comment: i shoudlnt say that, but.... i just LOVE `// good things happen` comment <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to the rescue. It's pretty straightforward to do using a regex and its associated `.test` method. The following regex ensures the string starts with one of the characters `b`, `e`, or `n` (not case sensitive), followed by exactly 8 digits:

```js
test1 = "B12345678";
test2 = "N123456789"; 
test3 = "x12345678";

const regex = /^[bBeEnN]{1}[0-9]{8}$/

console.log(regex.test(test1))
console.log(regex.test(test2))
console.log(regex.test(test3))
```

So, for your snippet, you could adapt it like this:

```js
$(function() {

$("input#id_wrT4duNEOW").blur(function() {
    var val = $("#id_wrT4duNEOW").val();
    if (/^[ben]{1}\d{8}$/i.test(val)) {
      // good things happen
    } else {
     // error message
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Just a note `/^[ben]{1}[0-9]{8}$/i`  using the `i` modifiyer you can make it case-insensitive.  Also `\d` will give you a digit.. So -> `/^[ben]{1}\d{8}$/i`

Comment: Can I ask how to add that to my code? What I'm trying isn't working. I'll try to edit my original post to show you what I mean.

Comment: @adamracstl I've edited the post to include one possible way of adapting your original code.

Comment: @CRice oh that's perfect. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
//1) must be 9 characters
//2) first character must be B, E, or N
//3) 8 characters past the first must be digits

var pattern = /^(B|E|N)\d{8}$/

console.log(pattern.test("weee"));
console.log(pattern.test("B12345678"));
console.log(pattern.test("A12345678"));
console.log(pattern.test("B123456789"));
```